# RestKit / CoreData: Duplicate objects inserted instead of merged when requesting the same URL twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

My application uses RestKit to GET from a URL, the payload of which contains a list of objects (hospitals) in JSON. The first time I hit the URL, everything works fine - the payload is correctly transformed into a group of `Hospital` managed objects and they are inserted into the persistent store (verified by performing a fetch request and comparing the results with the payload).

If I perform the GET a second time from the same URL, returning the same payload, RestKit inserts another group of `Hospital` objects (identical to the first group) into the persistent store. I would like RestKit to determine that the second group of `Hospital` objects are identical to the first, and then update the first group of objects if necessary.

The payload contains a unique identifier called `provider_number`.

I added a `provider_number` field to the `Hospital` model and ticked `Indexed`.

I set the identification attribute on the `RKEntityMapping` accordingly:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *) hospitalMapping {
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Hospital" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    [mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[ @"provider_number"]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[self hospitalAttributeDictionary]];
    return mapping;
}
```

I created the managed object cache on the `RKManagedObjectStore`, using the persistent MOC, per http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html#overview:

```
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

The `RKObjectManager` is configured to use the persistent MOC:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [managedObjectStore persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
```

The `RKObjectManager` is further configured with the response descriptor and the requested response MIME type.

The mapping operation is then enqueued:

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@""  
                     parameters:nil
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                           NSError *executeError = nil;
                           if([managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&executeError]) {
                              NSLog(@"Saved hospitals to persistent store.");
                           }
                           else {
                              NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store");
                           }
                        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                           UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                           [alertView show];
                        }];
```

Executing this twice causes duplicate object in the persistent store. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see the `provider_number` set in the data store (when you log the new managed object instances)?

Comment: p.s. you don't need to call `saveToPersistentStore:` in the success block - it's already been saved by then...

Comment: Hi @Wain, thanks for your response. Yes, the `provider_number` is being properly mapped: `RKMapperOperation.m:403 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    "" =     (
        "<Hospital: 0xa537e10> (entity: Hospital; id: 0xa52b500 <x-coredata:///Hospital/t296C047A-2D63-4AF4-9DDF-F5C422D3A10B15> ; data: { \n    \"provider_number\" = 450056;\n})",
    );
}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll remove the extraneous call to `saveToPersistentStore`.

Comment: Do you have another mapping for the same entity with the `identificationAttributes` set to something different?

Comment: No. There is only the one mapping.

Comment: You'll need to turn on trace logging and see what it says about finding existing items then

Comment: I've set logging on `RestKit/ObjectMapping` and `RestKit/CoreData` to `RKLogLevelTrace` - there is not anything about existing items. I see where the second iteration maps to new Core Data objects, but there doesn't seem to be anything explicitly saying that existing items were not found. What am I looking for? Log pasted to http://pastebin.com/Ntf8Vtf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this log:

> restkit.core_data:RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache.m:124 Found objects '(
>   )' using fetchRequest ' (entity: Hospital; predicate: (provider_number == nil); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )'

Restkit is looking for an existing item, but the predicate is wrong: `predicate: (provider_number == nil)`

It immediately isn't clear why. Put a breakpoint in `RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache.m` at the start of `managedObjectsWithEntity:attributeValues:inManagedObjectContext:` and check back up the stack to find out what `attributeValues` is being created with and why the `provider_number` isn't being completed correctly.

Comment: Indeed. I wonder why it's nil? My guess is RK is building that predicate involving `provider_number` because I added `provider_number` as an entity identification attribute, but if I understand this correctly, it looks like RK is then not populating the other side of the comparison with the value of `provider_number` for the object that RK just created. I'll set the breakpoint and dive into it...

Comment: Figured it out. RKTransformedValueWithClass() was returning nil because it couldn't resolve the entity's identification attribute to a type (it was Transformable). I changed the attribute's type to NSString * and identification works fine now. Thanks!